# How can I open my thermostat cover which is stuck due to using too much gasket maker material?

Tags: thermostat, gasket, gasket-maker

[image]I have to replace my thermostat with a new one.
I have removed all the bolts of thermostat cover in my car but the gasket maker material has caused the thermostat housing and thermostat cover to stick firmly to each other (acting like glue). I can't open it. It is extremely stubborn. I don't want to break anything so I avoided prying or applying too much force. How can I dissolve or remove the gasket maker material (between the parts) without damaging either of the parts?
The above image was taken a few years ago.

Comment: What is the vehicle in question? Can you provide an image of what you're talking about? More than likely if you were to use a putty knife and force it down into the area between the housing and to where it's well connect via the gasket maker, it'd slice the gasket maker and release the housing without issue ... without knowing what vehicle you're working on, I'm not going to give you that advice.

Comment: @Paulster My car is a Peugeot 406 1.8 16V and this is the picture of the housing and the cover: https://i.ibb.co/vmKCc2V/11.jpg  This picture was taken a few years ago before housing and cover were mated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using a putty knife, drive it down between the housing and cover (as you put it), tapping it gently with a hammer. This will separate the two halves and give you a "way in" between. After you've driven it down and split some of the sealant, you should find it fairly easy to push the putty knife away from the housing and separate the two halves. This may require a *bit* of prying, but it should separate the two without damaging anything other than the gasket and sealant.

You do not want to use a hammer on the cover, as it will most likely give before the sealant will. You are right, the stuff can be stubborn.

During reassembly, ensure the two halves are COMPLETELY clean. Use a fresh gasket and only use the sealant sparingly. You don't need too much as it will seal it with just a thin layer.

Comment: Sharpening the end of the putty blade will help, and it won't damage the metal parts.

Answer (score 1):

Having tried to tap something thin into the gasket all round, and failed, I'd remove the studs (maybe 3) holding the cover on, and tap the cover gently (initially!) all round, sideways, and slightly away from the lower part, if possible. Heat might help, but enough tapping will give it its freedom.